# FMU export of c code with structure as an input argument

Tags: c, fmi

My research project group is trying to export matlab code as FMU.
One of the way we came up with is generating c code from matlab script  and export c code as FMU.
I am curious if there is any tool for packaging c code as an FMU? If there is not, is there another way to achieve this?

**Updating the question after the answer from @mklingn**.
I have tried editing with **bouncingball.c** , but the problem I face is, in every example provided, variables are considered data type as either boolean or double. In my case one of the input is structure, for example my c file generated is

```
#include "mult.h"

/* Function Definitions */

/*
 * Arguments    : double u
 *                double v
 *                const struct0_T *m
 * Return Type  : double
 */
double mult(double u, double v, const struct0_T *m)
{
  double y;
  y = u * v * m->x[2];

  /*  fcn(u,v ,'parameter1',m,'parameter2',n) */
  return y;
}
```

and .h file generated is

```
#ifndef MULT_H
#define MULT_H
typedef struct {
  char y[6];
  double x[6];
} struct0_T;
extern double mult(double u, double v, const struct0_T *m);
#endif
```

so according to your point 2: such kind of exporting is not possible with FMI version 2.0. Did I understand your point correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the [FMU Software Development Kit for version 2.0](http://www.qtronic.de/doc/fmusdk.zip). It has several examples implemented in C, both for Co-Simulation (which I guess is what you want) and Model-Exchange.

You can use one of the examples as a starting point (e.g. fmu20/src/models/bouncingBall from the zip file linked above). It is quite some manual work to adapt it, but you learn a lot about the interface.

Two things to keep in mind:

1. Be aware that only small subset of Matlab features can be exported to C code. See [MATLAB Language Features Supported for C/C++ Code Generation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/matlab-language-features-supported-for-code-generation.html) for a list.
2. FMI does not yet handle array variables. This is [planned for version 3.0](https://fmi-standard.org/downloads/). So you are limited to passing scalar variables only.

The structure type you show above cannot be passed - as is - to an FMU. No calling program adhering to the standard can be aware how your internal structure is defined. They can only pass the primitive scalar data types specified by the FMI standard.

The *information*, however, can be passed. You could define a double model variable called e.g. *x2* and either modify the *mult* function to use it directly or rebuild the structure inside the FMU.